# Pandas: updating specific values in a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe of around 1000 samples. In a particular column there are approximately 800 samples with valid data and 200 with missing values dispersed irregularly through the population.

I have extracted the samples with missing values and filled with valid data from a different dataset as a csv.

I am trying to update the original dataframe with the corrected values but am finding it more difficult than I believe it should be, but I've been staring at it for long enough that I think I can no longer see the woods for the trees.

To illustrate the problem in code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_master = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                          'player_id':[53, 26, 74, 15, 63, 82],
                          'age':[25, np.NaN, 37, 13,53, np.NaN])

ageless = df_master[df_master.age.isna()]
ageless.to_csv('fill_ages.csv')
```

after filling the ages:

```
filled_ages = pd.read_csv('filled_ages.csv')
```

I have tried using a merge:

```
pd.merge(df_master, filled_ages, on=df_master['player_id'], how='left')
```

but I get a 'Check Duplicates' error.
I've also tried iterating over the dataframes:

```
for i in df_master.player_id:
    if i in filled_ages.player_id:
        df_master.age[df_master.player_id == i] = filled_ages.age[filled_ages.player_id == i]
```

but get a 'Copy on a slice' warning. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My suggestion was wrong, check out my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use pd.Series.map like this:

```
df_master['age'] = df_master['id'].map(filled_ages.set_index('id')['age'])\
                                  .fillna(df_master['age'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I've not tried maps before, but I'll give your suggestion a try and add an update

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks for your assistance, I hadn't been familiar with .map() but will be exploring it in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the file's index when reading it:

```py
filled_ages = pd.read_csv('filled_ages.csv', index_col=0)
```

Then you can just fill in the NaNs using the existing indices (assuming you didn't change them):

```py
df_master= df_master.fillna(filled_ages)
```

It will update the NaN values with values from the `filled_ages` dataframe with the same index. This will work as long as you preserved the index.

If you didn't preserve the index, and assuming that `player_id` is unique, you can use that as the index:

```py
master_df = master_df.set_index('player_id')
filled_ages = filled_ages.set_index('player_id')

master_df["age"] = master_df["age"].fillna(filled_ages["age"])
master_df = master_df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the problem seems to be that when I extracted the 'nan' samples, the resulting csv has 200 values, but the original dataframe has 1000 and the df.index doesn't match for each. the 'player_id' has unchanging values, unique for each player, hence me thinking I could use it to match them up again during the merge operation. Is this a naive approach?

Comment: The number of rows shouldn't be an issue. Why doesn't the index match? Did you change the index of `filled_ages`?

Comment: Updated the answer with an option to use `player_id` as the index.

Comment: I extracted only the 'player_id' and 'age' columns for the filled_ages export, thinking I was being clever :S But the suggestion about the maps worked, I wasn't a method I was familiar with. I appreciate you taking the time to offer your assistance though. I tried to upvote your replies but am told my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: I updated the answer to only use the `age` column, it should work. I believe using `fillna()` is better here, since it is much easier to understand what's going on, unlike the other answer.

Comment: You are correct, your answer is more recognisable, as far as being easy to read and understand. Is there a way I can upvote you? I think both answers worked and I think you both deserve the recognition for your solutions

Comment: Not unless you have the required reputation. Only one answer can be accepted.